# convert multiple values in one string to float

Tags: python, arrays, string, floating-point, data-conversion

I have a string like this `-99.00 -99.00  99.00   9.00 -99.00` and I want to convert all the numbers inside the string to float values and then append them to an array, how could I achieve that?
Between the values 99.00 and 9.00 there are 3 white spaces separating them .

The append part I would be able to do by myself if knew how to convert the values one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pythonic way to do this is using a list comprehension and `split`

```
my_string = '-99.00 -99.00 99.00 9.00 -99.00'
arr = [float(x) for x in my_string.split(' ')]
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[-99.0, -99.0, 99.0, 9.0, -99.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split and map  method

```
a =  '-99.00 -99.00 99.00 9.00 -99.00' 
print map(float, a.split(" "))
```

Result:

```
[-99.0, -99.0, 99.0, 9.0, -99.0]
```

Comment: Using `map` when on py3 could be more efficient, depending on the input string and the poster&#39;s usage. This is due to `map` becoming a lazy generator, as opposed to it generating the whole list up front. Granted string split doesn't do that.